# Checkbox in UserForm on startup not working

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I have a userform with 2 dropdowns which I normally not need so I build a checkbox and hide the dropdown menu and the text label. The checkbox is checked by default. But the dropdown and label isn't hidden when I start the UserForm. When I manually uncheck and check the checkbox after UserForm is started it's working. So I dont know why the checkbox seems to work but I need to uncheck/check it manually after every start of the UserForm.

I think I have to do something at the initial start of the userform?

```
Private Sub SortCheckBox(blnChecked As Boolean)
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("KurbeitragKinder").Range.Font.Hidden = 
CheckBox1.Value
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Label8.Enabled = False
Label8.Visible = False
Label9.Enabled = False
Label9.Visible = False
ComboBox6.Enabled = False
ComboBox6.Visible = False
ComboBox7.Enabled = False
ComboBox7.Visible = False
Else
Label8.Enabled = True
Label8.Visible = True
Label9.Enabled = True
Label9.Visible = True
ComboBox6.Enabled = True
ComboBox6.Visible = True
ComboBox7.Enabled = True
ComboBox7.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can put all this is a sub, say `SortCheckBox(blnChecked as Boolean)` then move your CheckBox1_Click code to this, and call it at the start up. and your check box click will then be `SortCheckBox(me.checkbox1.value)`  If you wanted to get a bit fancier, you could use the state of the check box instead of the true or falses, so `me.something.visible=me.checkbox1.value`

Comment: Thank you for your help. As im very new to userform and VBA (using it since 2 days) its hard for me to understand what to do but i will try... Can you just tell me how i call the new sub at the startup ?

Comment: I have edited my new code which is working. I cant use the "me.something.visible=me.checkbox1.value" because when the box is checked the text is visible and when its unchecked its hidden but that dosnt matter. I now have the same problem that the box is checked but the text isnt hidden until i unched and check it.

Comment: You can take care of a lot of these things in a `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`, but I *believe* you can also set the default values in the properties window of the object.

Comment: @dwirony i have set the option "Value" to "True" so its always checked. The problem is when i open the userform the textbox is checked but the dropdowns which should be hidden by the check box arent hidden. I need to uncheck the checkbox and check it again then its working. So i dont know why the text isnt hidden when the box is checked and i need to uncheck and check it again manually

Comment: @Juggybash that's because the `Click` handler only runs when the checkbox is clicked. You need to invoke that logic before that, either from the outside just before displaying the form, or from within, in the `Initialize` or `Activate` handler - and since you'll *also* want to invoke it when the checkbox is clicked, you'll want to extract that logic into its own procedure, rather than copy-paste it and have it in two places -- see answer below.

Comment: Side note, while @dwirony's second suggestion will work (setup the design-time state as needed, for every control), IMO having the initial state in the designer properties is obscuring it: it's much better to have actual code that runs on initialization, that makes the initial state crystal-clear, from the code, without needing to dig designer properties for every individual control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the controls on a `UserForm` when it is first displayed will be, by default, whatever the design-time state is; let's call this the "default state".

You can define what that *default state* is by configuring each control's individual properties, using the designer's *properties* toolwindow (F4).

If the form's *default instance* is shown, then its state will be preserved between calls:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

...unless the instance gets reset - which can easily happen if you `Unload` that form, or if the user clicks the red "X" button to close it: the instance is destroyed, and since forms have a predeclared ID (aka default instance), the object is automatically re-created the next time it's referenced - with whatever the default (design-time) state is. If you handle the `QueryClose` event and programmatically `Hide` the form when `CloseMode` is [`VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-constants) (and set the `Cancel` parameter to `True`, to prevent destroying the form instance and its state), then the state will be preserved ...and this can lead to unexpected or inconsistent behavior.

The solution is to make sure you always display a fresh new instance of the form, instead of the default one:

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show
End With
```

That way the form's state is guaranteed to always be the default/intended design-time state every time it's displayed, and you can access the form's state between `.Show` and `End With`. All you need to do is to handle `QueryClose` and cancel the form's destruction when the user clicks the "form control menu" aka "the X button".

Initializing a form will raise the `Initialize` event; if you're using the form's default instance (i.e. `UserForm1.Show`), then you can't really control exactly when this happens, but if you show a fresh new instance every time (i.e. `With New UserForm1`), then you are certain that this event will be raised exactly once, every time you need to show the form.

The `Initialize` event is raised as soon as the object is created, and that happens before the first member call is made against it (i.e. when the `New UserForm1` returns, the event has already executed). If you need to check a box *and then* initialize the form accordingly, then you might want to handle the `Activate` event instead, which will be raised when the form is actually displayed (i.e. when the `.Show` method is called):

```
With New UserForm1 'UserForm_Initialize runs
    .CheckBox1.Value = foo 'form state is accessible here
    .Show 'UserForm_Activate runs
    'UserForm_QueryClose runs
    foo = .CheckBox1.Value 'form state is accessible here
End With 'UserForm_Terminate runs
```

Looks like you want to run that `CheckBox1_Click` handler before the form is shown - problem is, event handlers aren't `Public`, **and you don't want them to be**.

The solution is to pull the logic into a `Public Sub`, invoke that procedure from the client code, *and* invoke it from the checkbox':

```
Public Sub InitializeFormState()
    Dim isChecked As Boolean
    isChecked = CheckBox1.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("KurbeitragKinder") _
                  .Range.Font.Hidden = isChecked
    Label8.Enabled = isChecked
    Label8.Visible = isChecked
    Label9.Enabled = isChecked
    Label9.Visible = isChecked
    ComboBox6.Enabled = isChecked
    ComboBox6.Visible = isChecked
    ComboBox7.Enabled = isChecked
    ComboBox7.Visible = isChecked
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    InitializeFormState
End Sub
```

And now your client code can look like this:

```
With New UserForm1
    .InitializeFormState
    .Show
    'consume form state here
End With
```

Or, you can invoke `InitializeFormState` from the form's `Initialize` or `Activate` handler, as needed:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    InitializeFormState
End Sub
```

Or

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    InitializeFormState
End Sub
```

In which case the procedure should probably be made `Private`, and there's no need to invoke it from the client code before the `.Show` method.

Comment: Thank you its working ! But its the other way around i want it. CheckBox checked = Text hidden CheckBox unchecked = Text visible. Right now its the other way around :(

Comment: Then you can rename `isChecked` to something more meaningful, and make it `thing = Not CheckBox1.Value` and instantly fix all the property assignments at once =)

Comment: Ive didnt changed the name and just set "thing = Not CheckBox1.Value" and its working perfectly ! Thank you soooooo much !!